# Challenges Encountered When Implementing Filtering Using Django's Filter Backends in Python Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, filtering, django-filter

I attempted to implement filtering using Django Filter Backends in order to filter my class-based view, but I encountered difficulties. I am unable to retrieve the desired values in my search.

this is my Setting.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS':['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '3/day',
        'user': '5/day',
        'jack': '10/day'
    },
}
```

and this is my views.py:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly
from .models import Student
from .serlizer import StudentSerlilizer
from rest_framework.throttling import AnonRateThrottle,UserRateThrottle
from . import thorttle



class StudentInfo(APIView):

    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]  # Apply JWTAuthentication
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]  # Apply IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly permission
    throttle_classes = [AnonRateThrottle,thorttle.JackRateThrottle]
    filterset_fields = ['city']


    def get(self, request, format=None):
        stu = Student.objects.all()
        serlizer = StudentSerlilizer(stu,many=True)
        return Response(serlizer.data)
    
    def post(self,request,format=None):
        request_data = request.data
        serlizer = StudentSerlilizer(data=request_data)
        if serlizer.is_valid():
            serlizer.save()
            msg = {'msg':'Your data has been saved'}
            return Response(msg)
        
        msg = {'msg':serlizer.errors}
        return Response(msg,status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and this is my urls:-

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView,TokenRefreshView,TokenVerifyView

urlpatterns = [
    path('gettoken/',TokenObtainPairView.as_view(),name="get_token"),
    path('refreshtoken/',TokenRefreshView.as_view(),name="refresh_token"),
    path('verifytoken/',TokenVerifyView.as_view(),name="verify_token"),
    path('studentinfo/',views.StudentInfo.as_view(),name="studentlist"),
    path('studentinfo/<int:pk>/',views.StudentRUD.as_view(),name="StudentRUD")
]
```

this is what i tried to get all the querie's with the city="Bhopal":-

http://127.0.0.1:8000/studentinfo/?city=Bhopal

I am receiving all the queries that I don't want; I only want the query that I searched for.

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "sno": 2,
        "name": "Rajveer",
        "roll": 23,
        "city": "Mandap",
        "pass_by": "user1"
    },
    {
        "sno": 3,
        "name": "Payal",
        "roll": 3,
        "city": "Bhopal",
        "pass_by": "user2"
    },
    {
        "sno": 4,
        "name": "harry",
        "roll": 5,
        "city": "Vizaywada",
        "pass_by": "m"
    },
    {
        "sno": 5,
        "name": "Singam",
        "roll": 6,
        "city": "Pune",
        "pass_by": "user1"
    },
    {
        "sno": 6,
        "name": "Bajirao",
        "roll": 8,
        "city": "Banglore",
        "pass_by": "user2"
    },
    {
        "sno": 7,
        "name": "add",
        "roll": 122,
        "city": "Mumbai",
        "pass_by": "m"
    }
]
```